# GBA Emulator Bug

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, webassembly

I've been trying to reverse engineer a GBA emulator I found online (https://gba.44670.org/), and I used a HTML extracter to try to replicate it. I wanted it to work offline, so I downloaded all of the scripts to my computer, and is running in off of there. However, after that, the "Choose File" button no longer appears, replaced with a "Loading, please wait..." text line. Diving into the code, I see it has something to do with WASM. The code is as follows:

```
<div id="wasm-loading">
            Loading, please wait...
        </div>
        <div id="select-rom" hidden>
            <input type="file" id="romFile" onchange="onFileSelected()" hidden /></p>
            <button onclick="$id('romFile').click()" id="btn-choose">Choose File...</button>
        </div>
```

Other mentions of WASM in the code is in a .js file, app.js:

```
function wasmReady() {
    romBuffer = Module._emuGetSymbol(1)
    var ptr = Module._emuGetSymbol(2)
    wasmSaveBuf = Module.HEAPU8.subarray(ptr, ptr + wasmSaveBufLen)
    ptr = Module._emuGetSymbol(3)
    imgFrameBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(Module.HEAPU8.buffer).subarray(ptr, ptr + 240 * 160 * 4)
    idata = new ImageData(imgFrameBuffer, 240, 160)

    isWasmReady = true
    document.getElementById('wasm-loading').hidden = true
    document.getElementById('select-rom').hidden = false

}
```

I was expecting that once I downloaded the scripts, it would work like normal. I mean, it still has access to the scripts it needs, right? I've tried hiding the text by changive the true/false statment in `document.getElementById('select-rom').hidden = false`, and vice versa, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

(BTW I'm pathing the files in vscode.dev. This is what it looks like: `<script src="/Scripts/44gba.js"></script> <script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script> <script src="/Scripts/localforage.js"></script> <script src=/Scripts/pako.min.js></script>`
)

Comment: Instead of trying to copy files from a live website, why not download the source from their github. It's open source.

Comment: A couple of errors I see. You shouldn't be putting your files in `Scripts/` directory. Instead you should have 6 files: `index.html` where you copy all the HTML of the page (including script tags). `app.js`, `pako.min.js`, `localforage.js`. And in build directory: `build/44gba.js`, `build/44gba.wasm`  that you will copy content from Dev Tools Network files list. Then you will have to set CORS origin in XHR request inside their `readAsync` method.

Comment: The rest of the solution will depend on how you want to use it locally. Do you want to create a localhost HTTP server that would serve the files? Or just want to launch `index.html` manually and let it do the rest? The WASM file is 7.7MB, it's the Emulator.

Comment: @KeitelDOG my plain is to run it in a file:// page. I have all of the files but build/44gba.wasm. is that the problem?

Comment: I updated my answer with a modified `build/44gba.js` that solved `file://` CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

To keep an App in local with script, keep in mind 2 things:

1. The script is already written and will look for resources (js, css, images) in the current App directory structure
2. The Request and File reading will be blocked by CORS from most browsers unless you deactivate CORS preflight check.

That is said, copy the same HTML you get in response of (https://gba.44670.org/), which will keep file structure. Here is the content I got (`index.html`):

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <title>44VBA</title>

</head>

<body>
    <style>
        a,
        a:visited {
            color: white;
        }

        html,
        body {
            position: fixed;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            touch-action: none;
            cursor: inherit;
        }

        body {

            background-color: #000000;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            font-family: 'Myriad Set Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        hr {
            color: white;
        }

        button {
            border: 2px solid white;
            background: transparent;
            color: white;
            padding: .5em;
        }

        .vk-round {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        .vk {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .vk-hide {
            background-color: transparent !important
        }

        .vk-touched {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) !important
        }

        .menu {
            background: rgb(32, 43, 56);
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        #gba-canvas {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        #vk-layer {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 3;
            touch-action: none;
        }

        #msg-layer {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            top: 40vh;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            z-index: 2;
        }

        textarea {
            background: transparent;
            color: #fff;
            border: 2px solid white;

        }

        /* textarea placeholder */
        textarea::placeholder {
            color: #666;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="pause-menu" class="menu" style="background: rgba(32,43,56,0.7);" hidden="">
        <button onclick="setPauseMenu(false)"> ← Back </button>
        <hr>
        Savegame management:<br>
        <button onclick="savBackupBtn()">Backup</button>
        <input type="file" id="sav-file" onchange="savRestoreBtn()" hidden="">
        <button onclick="$id('sav-file').click()">Restore</button>
        <hr>
        <label for="cfg-scale-mode">Screen filter:</label>
        <select id="cfg-scale-mode">
            <option value="0">Pixelated</option>
            <option value="1">Smooth</option>
            <option value="2">XBRZ</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cfg-mute">
        <label for="cfg-mute">Mute Sound</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cfg-turbo">
        <label for="cfg-turbo">Turbo mode</label><br>
        <div id="div-cht">
            Cheat Codes(backup your savegame before using it):<br>
            <textarea id="txt-code" style="width:100%" rows="10" placeholder="Cheat code:
GamesharkAdv: XXXXXXXX YYYYYYYY
CodeBreaker: XXXXXXXX YYYY"></textarea><br>
            <button onclick="chtSaveBtn()">Save Cheat Codes</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        Cloud Save:<span id="span-cloud-id"></span><br>
        <button onclick="dpOnConnectButtonClicked()" id="btn-dp-connect">Connect Dropbox</button><br>
        <button onclick="dpManualBtn(true)">↑ Upload</button>|<button onclick="dpManualBtn(false)">↓ Download</button><br>
    </div>
    <div id="welcome" class="menu">
        <h1 id="title">44VBA</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="wasm-loading" hidden="">
            Loading, please wait...
        </div>
        <div id="select-rom">
            <input type="file" id="romFile" onchange="onFileSelected()" hidden=""><p></p>
            <button onclick="$id('romFile').click()" id="btn-choose">Choose File...</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        Ver. 20230107 | <a href="https://github.com/44670/44vba">GitHub</a>
        <p>
            Your files are processed locally and won't be uploaded to any server.<br>
            This software should not be used to play games you have not legally obtained.<br>
            "GBA", "Game Boy Advance" are trademarks of Nintendo Co.,Ltd, This site is not associated with Nintendo in
            any way.
        </p>
        <div id="ios-hint" hidden="">
            Due to iOS limitations, please open this site(https://gba.44670.org) in <b>Safari</b>, and add it to your
            <b>Home Screen</b> by <b>Share Menu</b> to continue.
            <p style="text-align: center;">⬇⬇⬇</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="msg-layer" hidden="">
        <p id="msg-text">Gamepad disconnected.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="vk-layer" hidden="">
        <div class="vk-rect vk" data-k="menu" style="top: 25px; left: 591px; width: 150px; height: 25px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 25px;">Menu</div>
        <div class="vk-rect vk" data-k="turbo" style="top: 25px; left: 0px; width: 150px; height: 25px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 25px;">F.F.</div>
        <div class="vk-rect vk" data-k="l" style="top: 75px; left: 0px; width: 150px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;">L</div>
        <div class="vk-rect vk" data-k="r" style="top: 75px; left: 591px; width: 150px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;">R</div>
        <div class="vk-round vk" data-k="a" style="top: 175px; left: 676px; width: 65px; height: 65px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 65px;">A</div>
        <div class="vk-round vk" data-k="b" style="top: 200px; left: 585px; width: 65px; height: 65px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 65px;">B</div>
        <div class="vk-rect vk" data-k="select" style="top: 605px; left: 205.5px; width: 150px; height: 25px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 25px;">Select</div>
        <div class="vk-rect vk" data-k="start" style="top: 605px; left: 385.5px; width: 150px; height: 25px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 25px;">Start</div>
        <div class=" vk" data-k="left" style="top: 200px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;">←</div>
        <div class=" vk" data-k="right" style="top: 200px; left: 100px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;">→</div>
        <div class=" vk" data-k="up" style="top: 150px; left: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;">↑</div>
        <div class=" vk" data-k="down" style="top: 250px; left: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;">↓</div>
        <div class=" vk vk-hide" style="top: 150px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;" data-k="ul"></div>
        <div class=" vk vk-hide" style="top: 150px; left: 100px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;" data-k="ur"></div>
        <div class=" vk vk-hide" style="top: 250px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;" data-k="dl"></div>
        <div class=" vk vk-hide" style="top: 250px; left: 100px; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 35px; line-height: 50px;" data-k="dr"></div>
    </div>
    <canvas width="240" height="160" id="gba-canvas" style="width: 741px; height: 494px; left: 0px; image-rendering: pixelated;"></canvas>
    <script src="pako.min.js"></script>
    <script src="localforage.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="build/44gba.js"></script>




</body></html>
```

Then you can see the script path, that you will follow to create your files:

```
<script src="pako.min.js"></script>
<script src="localforage.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="build/44gba.js"></script>
```

And in addition, you need to download the WASM file (651KB compressed, and 7.7MB uncompressed). You can just download the compressed one here (you can find it in Network tab of Dev Tools): https://gba.44670.org/build/44gba.wasm

And finally, download all necessary files (and icon and pic if you want to, but not necessary):

- https://gba.44670.org/pako.min.js
- https://gba.44670.org/localforage.js
- https://gba.44670.org/app.js
- https://gba.44670.org/build/44gba.js
- https://gba.44670.org/build/44gba.wasm
- https://gba.44670.org/manifest.json

You will get a structure like this one:

[image]

Now, if you can deactivate CORS from your browser, then good. But if not, you must to Serve it from a local HTTP Server. One option is to install NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server , run `npm install --global http-server`. After that just navigate to project directory in terminal and start server:

```
npx http-server ./ --port 4000
```

And you will get the right screen and load a ROM and your done.

[image]

**EDIT : Solve Local CORS issue with simple Hack**

Since I know now you are on ChromeOS and technically don't know yet how to handle it with Node, NPM and HTTP-Server, I did a little hack for you and put the WASM binary content directly in a variable inside `build/44gba.js`, and return that binary content on the function readBinary so that it will bypass the CORS issue. An you can launch index.html directly. Here is the link for the new `build/44gba.js` file, just replace its content with this one : https://sendeyo.com/en/b02f94b524 , and you're all good. Here is what is changed:

```
const wasmData = `0061 736d 0100 0000 01c9 011e 6001 7f00
6002 7f7f 0060 0000 6001 7f01 7f60 037f
...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
0a00 41c0 8106 0b04 7064 6202`;

// other codes ...

readBinary = filename=>{
    var ret = new Uint8Array(wasmData);
    return ret;
    /* var ret = read_(filename, true);
    if (!ret.buffer) {
        ret = new Uint8Array(ret)
    }
    return ret
    */
}

// other codes ...
```

Comment: This really helped! Its just that plan is to use the code in chrome OS, which is super limited, and to run it in the file:// page. My understanding of this is that I did mainly everything g correct, as the code in index.html is the same as what I got. The only problem is that I forgot to add the wasm file. However, if I  pull the code from index.html, and replace the paths with https:// links to them, it works fine. The moment I download the code in vs code and use their pathing system, it just stops working. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: Also, what does the .wasm file do?

Comment: Chrome Browser, and other browsers will block any attempt to use local file content in the scripts. When you launch `index.html` directly, it will try to load the WASM file with `file://` protocol, hence get blocked by Browser CORS policy. You can disable CORS by starting browser with special tags in some cases. But when you replace it with HTTPS link, browser won't block it and it will pass CORS limit.

Comment: The `.wasm` file is contain Assembly codes to be executed on other coding environments, like in this case, Javascript. The WASM file is the GBA Emulator.

Comment: @George Since I know now you are on ChromeOS and technically don't know yet how to hande it with Node, NPM and HTTP-Server, I did a little hack for you and put the WASM binary content directly in a variable inside `build/44gba.js`, and return that binary content on the function `readBinary` so that it will bypass the CORS issue. An you can launch `index.html` directly. I will show you a link to download the hacked content of `build/44gba.js`.

Comment: About the "Solve Local CORS issue with simple Hack," it helped, and I was going to download the file, but the webpage you gave me shows a 502 bad gateway error. Any ideas?

Comment: the link for the hacked version of build/44gba.js is broken. It shows a 503 Bad Gateway Error.

Comment: @George It's still there, I just verified. You can get it directly from: https://sendeyo.com/get/d/b02f94b524 . I also created a GIST in Github: https://gist.github.com/KeitelDOG/e5b6439bf0c776f3c82ac8edcdc9664d . But you have to click the "view the full file" to show complete length, because it's truncated for being too long.

Comment: @George also you can create it manually too by copying Binary content as variable in backtick `...` and modify codes to use binary in variable directly. Or download file content in Github GIST directly.